# Watson Assistant isn't prompting for a required slot

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have set up a slot with "Check for" set to @service_type and "Save it as" set to $service_type, and added a prompt ("Will this be a medical, dental, physio, carer, or other appointment?") in the "If not present, ask" field. I also have added responses to display what is in $service_type (with a default "true" condition to indicate that the variable is empty."

When I test the node with an utterance that does not contain a match to the @service_type entity, I don't get the expected prompt. There is no output from the response block, either.

I haven't had this problem before, and it's got me baffled. What should I look for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it. The issue was caused by having an optional slot at the top of the list. I moved it to the bottom (after to mandatory slots) and it worked correctly again.